# Find an element in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Array looks so:

```
var arr = 
[{name: '1112B', 
  subname: 
   [
    {name: 'sub_1112B'}, 
    {name: 'sub_1112BA'}
   ]
  }, 
 {name: '2112B', 
  subname: 
   [
    {name: 'sub_2112B'},
    {name: 'sub_2112BA'}
   ]
 }];
```

After executing following code:
`arr.map(it => it.subname).find(i => i.name == 'sub_2112BA')` i got *undefined* but it is supposed to be '2112B'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your test string `sub2112BA` doesn't exists in your data.

Comment: sub_2112BA exists in name: '2112B'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr.map(it => it.subname)` will create nested array of `subname` and using .find() will return `undefined` since it iterate through a nested array, you could use `.flat()` and then use `find`after but it won't return the object containing the `subname` since you are iterating in the `subname` array, so instead you can filter the objects of the array and use find on each subname array to check if the desired `name`is there

```js
arr = 
[{name: '1112B', 
  subname: 
   [
    {name: 'sub_1112B'}, 
    {name: 'sub_1112BA'}
   ]
  }, 
 {name: '2112B', 
  subname: 
   [
    {name: 'sub_2112B'},
    {name: 'sub_2112BA'}
   ]
 }];
 
 res=arr.filter(x=>(x.subname.find(y=>y.name=="sub_2112B")))
 console.log(res)
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.filter` returns an array and also it will loop through the entire array. if you're really interested in first occurrence, can go with `x.find(d => !!d.subname.find(i => i.name == 'sub_2112BA'))`

Comment: @ENG1959 Please conceder accepting my answer if it helped clarifying the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use type-safe equal `===` in `find()`

Comment: Also you will find not find the string your looking for, but rather the object containing the string. You should not include the map call, if you want to get the object containing the search as a substring.